# Is React-Redux still useful as of 2023?

Tags: react-redux

Why use react-redux, when we have hooks such as useContext and useReducer in React.
What are the further advantages to using Redux alongside react, which are not present in react itself - and how worth are those advantages?

Comment: Lots of other better-performing options out there, you can try effector-react

Answer (score 1):

If you have a global useContext and/or/with useReducer then all components using that context will re render no matter if the part of the sate they use has changed or not, if you also have a handler that is not wrapped in useCallback then virtual DOM compare will fail and these component will cause DOM updates. You can have multiple small contexts but then you have multiple sources of your state (could be good or bad depending on your needs and implementation).

React could be used with your own observable and [useSyncExternalStore](https://reactjs.org/docs/hooks-reference.html#usesyncexternalstore) that has parts of global store or just one state for all components. With selectors it would prevent components from re rendering that did not have changed state.

If you don't want to write your own observable then you can just use Redux and connect it to React with react-redux.

Comment: Technically you can bypass the re-rendering with proper use of `useMemo`/`useCallback`. But I agree that an average user who just wants to deal with context and not any performance side-effects probably does not want to deal with them, so imho redux has it's place.

Comment: Or use SolidJS for better performance altogether

Comment: rip my question